# ASP.net Core SEO Middleware

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, seo

I have an angular app, and while google does index those now, many other sites do not.

What I want to do is create a custom ASP.Net Core middleware that will intercept requests from crawlers and serve them.

My question is this. Since humans wont see these pages, do I still need to make them pretty with CSS and follow the same theme as my site, or can I just use basic HTML to get the content that I need out there. Will basic HTML affect SEO at all?

The main page in question is jobs that our company posts on a jobs page. We want those jobs to be indexed, so can I just have a basic HTML page with all the job details?

Comment: I dont think that is a good idea, as crawlers will expect the page was  for humans with tags, colors, images, etc.

Comment: Great idea. I suggest to do some basic styling so that the crawlers belives this is a proper web page.